# unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"' bash while im trying to execute command outside a Docker container

Tags: python, bash, docker, shell, containers

I dont know what is happening here. Im executing a script that contains the following line:

```
var="${comand} bash -c  \"export PATH=/local/Miniconda3/bin:$PATH >> ~/.bashrc; /local/Miniconda3/bin/python3 scripts/DNAscan.py ${var}\""

echo "${var}"
$var
```

The output of that line is:

```
sudo docker exec -it image bash -c "PATH=/local//Miniconda3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin >> ~/.bashrc; /local/Miniconda3/bin/python3 scripts/DNAscan.py -format fastq -in input_output/input/test_data.1.fq.gz -in2 input_output/input/test_data.2.fq.gz -reference hg38 -alignment -variantcalling -annotation -iobio -out input_output/output/ -BED"
```

Bur when I try to execute it from the script it gives me the following error:

```
>>: -c: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
>>: -c: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

What can I do to solve this ?

Comment: Don't store commands in variables; variables are for data, not executable code or shell syntax. See [BashFAQ #50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) (and many many previous questions from people who've tried to do this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really want `docker exec` here at all.  This is a debugging tool that you can use to inspect a running container; I'd use it the same way I'd use a language-specific debugger like Python's `pdb`.

If you want to run a one-off command like this, you can use `docker run`.  For example,

```bash
docker run                         \
  --rm                             \ # clean up this container when done
  -v "$PWD/data:/app/input_output" \ # make local files available in the container
  my-image                         \ # image name to run
  scripts/DNAscan.py               \ # command to run
    -format fastq                  \
    -in input_output/input/test_data.1.fq.gz \
    -in2 input_output/input/test_data.2.fq.gz \
    -reference hg38                \
    -alignment                     \
    -variantcalling                \
    -annotation                    \
    -iobio                         \
    -out input_output/output/      \
    -BED
```

The command you show does tries to write a `.bashrc` file inside the container setting up `$PATH`.  However, most paths that run Docker containers don't actually read the `.bashrc` file at all.  In your image's Dockerfile, you can use the `ENV` directive to set `$PATH`.

```bash
ENV PATH=/local/Miniconda3/bin:$PATH
```

Now we've gotten rid of the `bash -c` wrapper entirely, which will resolve your quoting problem.

```bash
#!/bin/sh

docker run --rm -v "$PWD/data:/app/input_output" my-image "$@"
```

The `"$@"` syntax passes the wrapper script's arguments as the `docker run` command argument, preserving any spaces or other punctuation in the argument list.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. Please, could you explain to me in a little more detail how to use "$@"? How is that supposed to inject the arguments into the command?
Thank you very much

Comment: It's a [special parameter](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02) that expands to all of the positional parameters, the same as `"$1" "$2" "$3" ...` for as many parameters as there are.